# Unable to compile from ant but works from the command line, why?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, payment-gateway

Im having trouble making a class available to my project, in both ant and eclipse.

I'm using eclipse **juno+wpt**, and **ant 1.7**.

I'm integrating a payment plataform from a credit card company called CrediCard in Venezuela to an already working site.

We received a .zip package which contains the following:

[image: package structure received by bank]

Im using debian to develop since, to compile and run the project we were intsructed by the bank that we need a dependency called:

**libc6.1-1.so.2**

Needed for the project to run, which i dont really understand.
Also because the production OS its also un debian.

The package has a source example called ejemplodigest.java, with the instructions to compile it like this:

```
javac -classpath /home/DigestJavaLinux/classes ejemplodigest.java
```

And to run it like this:

```
java -Djava.library.path=/home/DigestJavaLinux/lib/ -classpath /home/DigestJavaLinux/:/home/DigestJavaLinux/classes ejemplodigest
```

These commands run perfectly on the command line. To run it the dependency **libc6.1-1.so.2** must be installed in debian.

How ever im not able to even compile the code with ant, when i include the corresponding lines in my project and add the classpath to the ant's javac task. I get the error

```
symbol  : class OasisEMSecIm
    [javac] location: class com.bamboo.catW3.business.impl.MainHtmlController
    [javac]          OasisEMSecIm digest= new OasisEMSecImp();
```

In the declaration of the class, and the imports:

```
import OasisEM.*;
import eMerchantServlet.*;
```

are not found:

```
OasisEM does not exist.
```

This is the example source given:

```
//import OasisEM.*;
import java.*;
// import eMerchantServlet.*;

class ejemplodigest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String varMerchant = "00260364";        // Merchant ID
        String varStore = "0";                  // Store ID
        String varTerm = "4001";                // Term ID
        String varTotal = "12345445";           // Monto de Transaccion
        String varCurrency = "937";             // Codigo de Moneda
        String varOrder_id = "444444";          // Order Id
        String varDigest;                       // Valor de Digest


        OasisEMSecImp digest= new OasisEMSecImp();
        varDigest = digest.getDigest(varTotal,varOrder_id,varMerchant,varStore,varTerm,varCurrency);

        System.out.println ("Merchant ID :" + varMerchant);
        System.out.println ("Store ID :" + varStore);
        System.out.println ("Term ID :" + varTerm);
        System.out.println ("Total :" + varTotal);
        System.out.println ("Currency :" + varCurrency);
        System.out.println ("Order ID :" + varOrder_id);
        System.out.println ("Digest " + varDigest);

    }
}
```

I'm not able to make Eclipse recognise them either, i have tried adding the class folder to the Eclipse, making the class a jar and adding it.

I checked and the paths are correctly received by the ant task, with all the others dependencies which work fine.

ANT Question: Why does the example source compiles with the command line, but when adding the same lines to a method in my project and adding the classpath to the class folder it does not compile ?

Eclipse Question: How can i make Eclipse recognise the class OasisEMSecImp ?

**UPDATE**

Hello, the ant file is a little long, how ever i'll paste what i think is the relevant part:

```
<path id="library.digest.classpath">
            <pathelement location="../../digest/classes"/>
        </path>

 <path id="catw.module.classpath">
        <path refid="library.blazeds.classpath"/>
        <path refid="library.hibernate3.classpath"/>
        <path refid="library.jta.classpath"/>
        <path refid="library.log4j.classpath"/>
        <path refid="library.mail.classpath"/>
        <path refid="library.oreilly.classpath"/>
        <path refid="library.spring-2.0.7.classpath"/>
        <path refid="library.velocity.classpath"/>
        <path refid="library.jexcel.classpath"/>
        <path refid="library.tomcat_5.classpath"/>
        <path refid="library.digest.classpath" />
        <pathelement location="../catw-common/build/catw-common.jar"/>
    </path>


<javac destdir="${catw.output.dir}" debug="${compiler.debug}" nowarn="${compiler.generate.no.warnings}" memorymaximumsize="${compiler.max.memory}" fork="true">
            <compilerarg line="${compiler.args.catw}"/>
            <bootclasspath refid="catw.module.bootclasspath"/>
            <classpath refid="catw.module.classpath"/>
            <src refid="catw.module.sourcepath"/>
            <patternset refid="excluded.from.compilation.catw"/>
        </javac>
```

I debugged the catw.module.classpath and the location is correct.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Hello Jermaine. I believe i have set the classpath correctly. I updated the question with the new classpath. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have understood the problem and found a work around for my situation, i explain it in my [answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15576305/unable-to-create-jar-when-adding-the-package-declaration).

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't set your path in ant correctly. You use relative path in your path element. So please make sure your basedir of the project is set correctly. You may also need to set the verbose to true for some helpful hints.