# unable to create jar when adding the package declaration

Tags: java, package, javac

I received a very simple class with some folders that compiles like this without problems:

```
javac -classpath /home/DigestJavaLinux/classes DigestClass.java
```

In the classes folder i have one .class file called **OasisEMSecImp.class**

How ever I need to import the class and use its method in another project, the method generates a digest string for the bank to check a transaction, and receives the total and other parameters.

If I add

package digestclass;

to the begining of the class it does not work, i get the error:

```
digestclass/DigestClass.java:136: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class OasisEMSecImp
location: class DigestClass
        OasisEMSecImp digest= new OasisEMSecImp();
        ^
digestclass/DigestClass.java:136: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class OasisEMSecImp
location: class DigestClass
        OasisEMSecImp digest= new OasisEMSecImp();
                                  ^
2 errors
```

**UPDATE:**
This is the file. It compiles without the package declaration:

```
package digestclass;

import java.*;

class DigestClass {
    private String varMerchant;
    private String varStore;                    // Store ID
    private String varTerm;             // Term ID
    private String varTotal;            // Monto de Transaccion
    private String varCurrency;             // Codigo de Moneda
    private String varOrder_id;         // Order Id
    private String varDigest;                       // Valor de Digest


    public DigestClass(String varMerchant, String varStore, String varTerm,
            String varTotal, String varCurrency, String varOrder_id,
            String varDigest) {
        super();
        this.varMerchant = varMerchant;
        this.varStore = varStore;
        this.varTerm = varTerm;
        this.varTotal = varTotal;
        this.varCurrency = varCurrency;
        this.varOrder_id = varOrder_id;
        this.varDigest = varDigest;
    }

    public String generateDigest(){
        OasisEMSecImp digest= new OasisEMSecImp();
        varDigest = digest.getDigest(this.varTotal,this.varOrder_id,this.varMerchant,this.varStore,this.varTerm,this.varCurrency);
        return varDigest;
    }

}
```

Why ? how to fix this ?
Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Which class are you adding the package declaration to? Note that you'll find life much simpler if a) you keep your source layout matching your package layout and b) you use an IDE to build your code until you're more confident about Java as a language.

Comment: Hello, im adding the package declaration to the DigestClass.java. Im trying to add feature to a big project of ours which is already set in  eclipse, intellij, and the flex part in adobe flex. Im using spring+hibernate on the back end. This question is a different aproach to get the class working because I could never make the OasisEMSecImp class to be recognized by Eclipse nor Ant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15351012/unable-to-compile-from-ant-but-works-from-the-command-line-why . Its very frustating.! i will add the class file to the question since its very simple. Thank you

Comment: Is `OasisEMSecImp` in just the default package? (That's a bad idea to start with, unfortunately.)

Comment: Im sorry, I dont understand your question, or your suggestion, Im sorry, could you please clarify a little ? thank you

Comment: I'm asking what package the `OasisEMSecImp` class is in. It's odd to have a class in the default package, but based on the location you're providing, that's what it seems you've got. I'd expect Eclipse to be able to pick it up very easily... I suggest you simplify things to a project which *just* depends on that class, and *just* creates a new instance - so just about 5 lines of code in a new class, and OasisEMSecImp as the only dependency.

Comment: I think i understand now, well I was given this package by the bank, I dont know if its default or it can be called in some way, its just a .class file. Is there a why to check this ?

Comment: Well you could try running `javap -c OasisEMSecImp` to start with. But as I say, try a simple diagnostic test class for now. I think you're being overwhelmed by the complexity of your real project.

Comment: That is what i was trying to do when i created this simple file. What could make a class to compile without the package declaration but not compile with the package declaration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i understand was the cause of the problem and what i did to go around it.

Like John Skeet pointed out, the class i was trying to use

```
OasisEMSecImp
```

Was compiled originally in the default package, which means that when it was compiled, the declaration

package example.package.OasisEMSecImp

At the beginning of the class was not used. As a consequence it can not be called from a class that does belongs to a package, and cant be integrated to my current project, which is pretty complex and uses packages declarations in every class.

The workaround was, i created a new and very simple application which works through command line and can be called from my application through exec, for example:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java " +
                                                    "-Djava.library.path=/home/ernesto/DigestJavaLinux/lib " +
                                                    "-classpath /home/ernesto/workspace/digestUserTest/bin:/home/ernesto/workspace/digestUserTest/lib/digestgenerator.jar: " +
                                                    "ARGUMENTS");
```

I understood this was the situation thanks to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283816/how-to-access-java-classes-in-the-default-package)

I hope this helps someone. And thank you for your help.